# How to call OnRequestPermissionResult method from Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, adapter

I want to make a phone call using the number displayed on the view in the recycler view.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewholder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = userlist[position]

    holder.txtFirstName.text = currentItem.firstName
    holder.txtLastName.text = currentItem.lastName
    holder.txtAge.text = currentItem.phonenumber.toString()
    num = currentItem.phonenumber.toString()

    holder.call.setOnClickListener {
        val number: String = currentItem.phonenumber.toString()
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
            ) != PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                context as Activity,
                arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE),
                REQUEST_CALL
            )
        } else {
            val dial = "tel:$number"
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial))
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to override OnResquestPermissionResult() inside the adapter.

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CALL) {
        if (grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            val number: String = num
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    context,
                    android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
                ) != PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    context as Activity, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE),
                    REQUEST_CALL
                )
            } else {
                onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults)
                val dial = "tel:$number"
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial))
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

}
```

if I try to override OnResquestPermissionResult() inside the activity I am not able to pass the current phone number from the view.

Comment: You have to use the interface and call them inside the activity

Answer (score 0):

I removed this whole code:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
requestCode: Int,
permissions: Array<out String>,
grantResults: IntArray
) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CALL) {
        if (grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            val number: String = num
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    context,
                    android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
                ) != PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    context as Activity, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE),
                    REQUEST_CALL
                )
            } else {
                onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults)
                val dial = "tel:$number"
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dial))
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

}
```

and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Dont do that, return your click call back into your activity or fragment, then do your request permission like this

[Request permission in android](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-how-to-request-permissions-in-android-application/amp/)

or this, new way of get permission

[Request permission in android with activity result api](https://medium.com/@ajinkya.kolkhede1/requesting-runtime-permissions-using-new-activityresult-api-cb6116551f00)